# Invalid Window Handle when closing a WinForm that hosts a WPF UserControl that hosts a Windows Forms control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a program that is made by a bunch of different people over many different years. Some apps are written in Winforms, some are written in WPF. I have a WPF user control that I use in some windows (WPF), and I am trying to place it into one of the Winforms windows of my program. I have both a WPF and WinForms version of this control, the WinForms ones is very complicated and somewhat buggy compared to my new WPF version, which is why I am placing it into the older WinForms window.

This WPF Usercontrol has a WinForms control inside of it because I cannot find a WPF version of the control that I need (a hexbox). Inside of my winforms form, I have placed an ElementHost that is hosting this UserControl(WPF). It works just fine until I close the window, which is when I get a Win32Exception saying InvalidWindowHandle. There is no useful stacktrace.

[image: Exceptionthrown]

When I close the form, I dispose of interpreterWPF, the elementhost for it. When disposing interpreterWPF, it in turn disposes the hexbox and it's WinFormHostedControl.

- interpreterWPF: The WPF Usercontrol
- interpreterWPFElementHost: The WinFormsElementHost
- PathfindingEditor: The WinForms form that hosts all of this

When I close PathfindingEditor, I am disposing of many things to prevent memory leaks.

```cs
(pathfindingeditor.cs)
private void PathfindingEditor_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Nullify things to prevent memory leaks
            interpreterWPF.Dispose();
            interpreterWPFElementHost.Child = null;
            interpreterWPFElementHost.Dispose();
            ...
(interpreterwpf.xaml.cs)
public override void Dispose()
        {
            Interpreter_Hexbox = null;
            Interpreter_Hexbox_Host.Child.Dispose();
            Interpreter_Hexbox_Host.Dispose();
        }
```

I am not sure what else to do at this point. The new WPF control that is replacing the winforms control is much simpler and is far less buggy. Changing the old form over to WPF would be great but I have not found a suitable library for the complicated task that it needs to perform and Winforms hosted elements in WPF have a lot of drawbacks, which is why I am not going farther than a hexbox.

I have read up on Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown() but this seems to completely shutdown the WPF UI thread. I doubt this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Don't set anything to `null`. Just `Dispose`. I'm not saying that this will solve the issue, but it's itself an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the AutomationProperties.NameProperty of the WPF root element of the ElementHost to some valid string e.g. as follows:

```
elementHost.HandleCreated += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                             {
                                 HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(elementHost.Child);
                                 AutomationProperties.SetName(source.RootVisual, "elementHost");
                             };
```

I received this exception with the following, very short callstack when the Visual Studio debugger was attached:

`Source    "WindowsBase"
StackTrace "at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, Int32 nMaxCount)"`

Without debugger the exception is not visible.

The exception is raised from within WPF framwork method `System.Windows.Automation.Peers.GenericRootAutomationPeer.GetNameCore` because the already disposed window handle `base.Hwnd` of the WPF part of the ElementHost is used in the method as follows:

```
namespace System.Windows.Automation.Peers // from PresentationCore.dll
{
public class GenericRootAutomationPeer : UIElementAutomationPeer
{
    ...
    protected override string GetNameCore()
    {
        string text = base.GetNameCore();
        if (text == string.Empty)
        {
            IntPtr hwnd = base.Hwnd;
            if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(512);
Throws  ======>     MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(new HandleRef(null, hwnd), stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
                    text = stringBuilder.ToString();
                }
                catch (Win32Exception)
                {
                }
                if (text == null)
                {
                    text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Setting the AutomationProperties.NameProperty ensures that `base.GetNameCore()` returns a valid string, which in turn causes the problematic code to be skipped.

Comment: Thank you Roland. I don't really love the solution, but it fixed the issue. Did you find a more smooth solution?

Comment: @Bjqn are you on .NET Framework or on .NET Core? It seems Core still has this issue, but maybe it'd be worth filing it as a bug to get it fixed by 6.0.

Comment: @SörenKuklau I'm using .Net Framework 4.7.2